# Record Lock Issue for REST endpoint

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, locking

I have built a REST endpoint, which writes data(Accounts) to Salesforce. Currently, for a single record, there could be multiple (20-30 times) upserts within 1-to-5 seconds. Behind the scenes, it's a complicated scenario. Also, I can not make it asynchronous using staging object.

**Why Upsert**: As I may have to query the record before deciding on insert/update(which would slowdown the service, as the records are in millions)

Now the error I face is

> DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: UNIQUE_ID__c duplicates value
>   on record with id: 0010Q00000ABDA

What could be possible solution to this?

Comment: Breaking down `upsert` into `insert`/`update` is more efficient than using `upsert`. You may actually like to go that route.